# Getting error .\config.cmd : VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://

Tags: devops, agent

Running on premise Azure DevOps server. Trying to setup agent for pipeline.
Error in log file: [2021-12-02 17:21:20Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://

Have a Basic authentication setup. Have users granted access to site.

Here is the command line in powershell.

```
\config.cmd --unattended --url https://FQDN_Server/Bill_Test/ --auth negotiate --userName Domain\User --password PASSWORD --token h6mgqztjnx5zbam7rmmdo5gnb4gz3xndvwyqotofxuycx4x74uha --pool SQLServer --agent devAgent --acceptTeeEula
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying to install the agent for a particular deployment group?

Comment: I am setting up the agent on a dev SQL instance away from the install of Azure DevOps Server. It's the first time setting up the agent. I checked permissions and it is all setup.

Comment: I added steps below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below steps:

Download the release agent zip file and place it inside the downloads folder of release machine

Then execute below 2 PS scripts to extract in c drive

PS C:> mkdir agent ; cd agent
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$HOME\Downloads\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.153.1.zip", "$PWD")

Point to c drive agent folder and execute below command.

.\config.cmd --deploymentpool --deploymentpoolname "YOUR_DEP_POOL_NAME" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://YOUR_TFS_SERVER/';

While installing when it prompts for authentication type, enter as  Negotiate. Then provide username and password

Comment: Displays the following:
PS C:\agent> .\config.cmd --deploymentpool --deploymentpoolname "DB_Agent" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://hwdwware1.health.co.jeffco.us/';


>> Connect:

Comment: what happened when you ran the command? Any error message? what value you gave for Connect:- ?

Comment: Could not type anything next to connect.

Comment: are you sure the --url is correct?

Comment: PS C:\agent> .\config.cmd --deploymentpool --deploymentpoolname "DB_Agent" --agent $env:HWPXBL01 --runasservice --work '_work' --url https://hwdwware1.health.co.jeffco.us/Bill_Test';
- C:\agent\_diag\Agent_20211207-204558-utc.log .\config.cmd : An error occurred: MissingValueOptionError
At line:1 char:1 + .\config.cmd --deploymentpool --deploymentpoolname "DB_Agent" --agent ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (An error occurr...alueOptionError:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
Unrecognized command-line input arguments: ''.

Comment: apostrophe mark is missing in the url. It should be as  --url 'hwdwware1.health.co.jeffco.us/Bill_Test';

Comment: I tried the following: .\config.cmd --unattended --url https://<FQDN>/Bill_Test/ --auth negotiate --userName health\<user> --password <password> --token xftv567wmjeyo4vk4thks4r3pp6hbo3njn4sddummca4liubfztq --pool DB_Agent --agent devAgent --acceptTeeEula

.\config.cmd : VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://hwdwware1.health.co.jeffco.us.

Comment: Seems like access issues or could be a certificate issue. Did you check with the IT or TFS admins?

Comment: Checked the log, which is created by creating the agent, and this is what I received.
[2021-12-09 20:33:18Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://<FGDN>.

Comment: Are you able to PING / telnet the URL - https://<FGDN>